# Convert Datatypes in SSIS, Possible?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, integer, type-conversion, expression

i am currently having some difficulties trying converting a Unicode character string (DT_WSTR) into an INT

this is what i have

(Note most writings are in German, but i think someone who has worked with SSIS will unterstand anyways)

[image: DatatypeConversion]

Data Type selected: A four-byte, unsigned integer.but all it does is fail terribly

[image: SSIS Error]

Comment: Yes, completely possible but something is awry with your data values. Put a data viewer between `C1` and the `DataType Conversion` Observe the values of `ReiseID` Are there clearly non-integer values in there?

Comment: Can you show the error message you are getting?

Comment: No, i can't see no message

Comment: Like @billinkc say, something wrong in your data, don't convert just write to table or from dataviewer examine data. Error can be viewed in OUTPUT tab when you executing package.

Comment: @gberisha - When you point your mouse at the red 'X' do you get an error message in the tooltip? Or build your package and post the output from the 'Build' message window, if it's a runtime error post the output of the 'Messages' window. Another way to find the bad data would be to write the error output of the Data Conversion to a file or table in your database. Then you can see the rows causing the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try Derive Column component instead of Data Type Conversion.